# Display Chinese (and other non Latin) characters in PDF or PNG created by PHP

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, pdf-generation, png

How can I display Chinese (and Russian and any character) in a PDF or PNG created by PHP. The example code below display two blocks, not 测试. If I try Arabian, I see text, but it looks different from the input.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$text = '测试';
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 200);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 1400, 600, $white);

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf';

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 40, 0, 10, 100, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The font file is copied from my Ubuntu desktop.

I've tried the same creating a PDF using dompdf (with font DejaVuSans), which should be the end result, but that failed too. I guess it's the same problem. I tried tcpdf, which displays Russian and Arabian, so that is an improvement.

If I can create a PNG or something that can be used inside the PDF, that will do as well.

Comment: look for a chinese font and use that on `imagettftext` i also went through the same problem a long time ago

Comment: The problem is that it's not Chinese only. It should work for Russian, Malaysian etc as well. That would mean I should test for which language is used and as the text is user input and can be a mix. When using Arabian, it does output something, but that doesn't look like the original input.

Comment: The problem is that current text construction and fonts work with a strong Western bias: left to right, top to bottom, separate characters, with spaces between words. Right to left is not a problem (e.g. Hebrew), although the output device needs to be aware of it. However, in Arabic the letter forms themselves change according to where each letter appears in a word: at the beginning, in the middle, and at the end. So your font engine needs to implement that as well. By the way: "test for which language is used" is really, really hard. What I describe are technically only *script* differences.